# How can I append turtles created in for loop to a list to extract subsequently

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I'm trying to code a turtle racing programme where I have 6 turtles of different colors racing to the finish line. (They each get random distances to move each time) I want to append the turtles to a list after they pass the finish line, so there will be 1st place, 2nd place etc.

However, the `turtle.clear()`function doesn't seem to clear the turtles off the screen, and they instead keep racing forever, past the finish line. I'm also not sure what the turtle's names are given that they were all created in a `for` loop, so i'm not sure how to differentiate them in `podium`

Here is part of my code:

```py
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
distances = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
colors = ["red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "purple"]
y_cors = [-70, -40, -10, 20, 50, 80]
podium = []
all_turtles = []
 
for turtle_index in range(0, 6):
    tim = Turtle(shape="turtle")
    tim.color(colors[turtle_index])
    all_turtles.append(tim)
    tim.penup()
    tim.goto(x=-230, y=y_cors[turtle_index])

while is_race_on:
    for turtle in all_turtles:
        random_dist = random.choice(distances)
        turtle.forward(random_dist)
        if turtle.xcor() >= 200:
            podium.append(turtle)
            turtle.clear()
# More code down below for printing of winners through the podium
```

Comment: Did you try to check whether the `if turtle.xcor() >= 200:` condition is ever actually satisfied? Did you try to check e.g. whether the `podium.append(turtle)` code happens, and whether `podium` thus ends up with turtles in it? Does it? "i'm not sure how to differentiate them in podium" - well, each one draws in a different colour, right? How about using that? "I'm also not sure what the turtle's names are" - *what do you mean by "name"*? Why should any given turtle have a name, or exactly one name?

Comment: (Hint: If I call you "coconut", based on your Stack Overflow user name, that doesn't mean that the word "coconut" somehow becomes an intrinsic component of your existence. It's just a label that's applied to you (by me) *externally*. Your name is not "yours" in the same way that, for example, your nose is.)

Comment: Please share a runnable [mcve]. Right now, `podium` and `y_cors` are not defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so I managed to find a solution to my question above by deleting each turtle from the `all_turtles` list after their `x_cor >= 200`. I also added them to the `podium`list using their colors.

Here is my code:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
import random
import time

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(width=500, height=400)
bet = screen.textinput(prompt="Who do you think will win? Enter a color: ", 
title="Make a bet!")
colors = ["red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "purple"]
y_cors = [-70, -40, -10, 20, 50, 80]
distances = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
all_turtles = []
podium = []

for turtle_index in range(0, 6):
    tim = Turtle(shape="turtle")
    tim.color(colors[turtle_index])
    all_turtles.append(tim)
    tim.penup()
    tim.goto(x=-230, y=y_cors[turtle_index])

while len(all_turtles) > 0:
    for turtle in all_turtles:
        if turtle.xcor() >= 200:
            podium.append(turtle.pencolor())
            all_turtles.remove(turtle)
        else:
            random_dist = random.choice(distances)
                turtle.forward(random_dist)

screen.bye()

first = podium[0]
second = podium[1]
third = podium[2]

print(f"PODIUM!\nFirst: {first}\nSecond: {second}\nThird: {third}")

if bet in podium:
    if bet == first:
        print("\nCongrats! The turtle you voted for won!")
    elif bet == second:
        print("\nCongrats! The turtle you voted for came in second!")
    elif bet == third:
        print("\nCongrats! The turtle you voted for came in third!")
    else:
        print(f"\nThe turtle you voted for ranked number {podium.index(bet)}")
else:
    print("\nYou had an invalid bet.")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `turtle.clear()` only clears the turtle's drawing, it doesn't delete/hide it.

If you want to hide your turtle you could do `turtle.hide()`, and if you wanted to delete it you could do `del turtle` but I would just use `all_turtles.remove(turtle)`:

```py
while is_race_on:
    for turtle in all_turtles:
        random_dist = random.choice(distances)
        turtle.forward(random_dist)
        if turtle.xcor() >= 200:
            podium.append(turtle)
            all_turtles.remove(turtle)
```

There are also some other improvements that could be made:

```py
from turtle import Turtle # you don't use screen

distances = range(1, 11) # does the same thing
colors = ["red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "purple"]
y_cors = range(turtle)
podium = []
all_turtles = [Turtle(shape="turtle") for i in range(6)] # init like this is better

for t in range(all_turtles): # t is standard name for turtles
    t.color(colors[turtle_index])
    t.penup()
    t.goto(-230, y_cors[turtle_index]) # no need to specify (x=, y=)

while is_race_on:
    for t in all_turtles: # don't overwrite name turtle (from import)
        random_dist = random.choice(distances)
        t.forward(random_dist)
        if t.xcor() >= 200:
            podium.append(turtle)

        all_turtles.remove(t)

# More code down below for printing of winners through the podium
```

Comment: I usually specify `x=` and `y=` to make it easier for people unfamiliar with turtle to understand, and myself when checking for bugs in the code.

Comment: Yes, but it's implied that coordinates are in the form `(x, y)`. If you find it easier though, you can do that.